# ThreeJS get element (Mesh) by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js, mesh

I have a Mesh object in `Three.JS`.
How can i get that Mesh object with id, and change its position, like `$(#"sample")` in jQuery.
Or any better idea to change the position of an objects, in the middle of the code.

```
var voxel = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(x, y, z), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(...))
voxel.id = "sample";
scene.add(voxel);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be safe, don't overwrite the existing `Object3D.id`.

```
var objects = {};

mesh1.id2 = "mesh1";
objects[ mesh1.id2 ] = mesh1;

mesh2.id2 = "mesh2";
objects[ mesh2.id2 ] = mesh2;

objects[ "mesh2" ].position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
```

EDIT: `Object3D` has a property `userData` now. So you could use this pattern:

```
mesh1.userData.id = "mesh1";
objects[ mesh1.userData.id ] = mesh1;
```

three.js r.73

Comment: first of all thank you for your attention;
I did what you said, and the position of that Object member changed, but it doesn't make any change in my scene!
how can i update my scene to show the new positions?
i have to remove that object from the scene and re add it, or ...?

Comment: Ok, that's work!
I just add this at the top of your code:
mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
thanks